# Unable to add Navigation Items on Navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have Used a Navigation controller, IN my application within a TAbbar controller, the problem I am facing is I am unable to add Navigation bar Items to the navigation bar of a particular controller

when I do

```
self.navigationCOntroller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=aBArButtonItem;
```

Nothing is shown

When I do

```
self.tabController.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBArButtonItem=aBArButtonItem
```

then the same item is being added to all the viewCOntrollers in the Tabbarcontroller, I wan to display different bar button Items on different Controllers, Any Ideas how I can Achieve this??

Comment: Is `self.navigationController != nil` ?

Comment: no its not nil, the navigation conrolller is present and viewable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I wasnt able to add any navigation Item  because the TabbarCOntroller was the Container View, the following Code Helped Me out

```
  self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=right;
```

I also Had to override this code in the second ViewCOntroller with

```
  self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
```

Only then I was able to add and respond to the NavigationItems in the Navigation Bar

Answer (score 0):

try the following `code`

```
UINavigationController * navController = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:[self.tabBarController selectedIndex]];
    navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=aBArButtonItem;` try `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=aBArButtonItem;`. This way you access the `navigationItem` from your view controller, not from the entire navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

The `navigationItem` you're interested in is a property of your `viewController`, not the `navigationController` or `tabBarController`.

So if you try:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aBArButtonItem;
```

you'll have more success!